# How to setup a free trial in Shopify Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I will like to setup a free trial in my shopify rails app. I am using the official Shopify Rails app gem https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app. The config for billing looks like this

```
config.billing = ShopifyApp::BillingConfiguration.new(
charge_name: "Apps",
amount: 6.99,
interval: ShopifyApp::BillingConfiguration::INTERVAL_EVERY_30_DAYS,
currency_code: "USD", # Only supports USD for now)
```

How do I add an option for free trial ?  I have had a look at this documentation https://shopify.dev/apps/billing/purchase-adjustments/free-trials but I dont think the api for a free trial is included in the config of the shopify rails gem

Comment: I think you are looking for a [`RecurringApplicationCharge`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/shopify_api/ShopifyAPI/RecurringApplicationCharge#initialize-instance_method)

Comment: This might answer your question -> https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/pull/1464

Answer (score 0):

I don't remeber that free trials are supported by the Shopify Billing API.

In the past I needed to implement the free trial functionality myself, outside of the Shopify Rails gem.

One way you could do this is by creating a new plan in your app that is free, and then using the Shopify API to create a new recurring application charge for that plan

Answer (score 0):

At the moment shopify_app gem doesn't support adding `test` property when creating a new charge.

If you really want to add it you gonna have to implement it yourself.

[Here is how](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/applicationcharge#post-application-charges)

```rb
test_session = ShopifyAPI::Utils::SessionUtils.load_current_session(
  auth_header: request.auth_header,
  cookies: request.cookies,
)

application_charge = ShopifyAPI::ApplicationCharge.new(session: test_session)
application_charge.name = "Super Duper Expensive action"
application_charge.price = 100.0
application_charge.return_url = "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com"
application_charge.test = true
application_charge.save!
```